# Is there an integer-based version of System.Windows.Size anywhere in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I feel silly asking such a basic question after so long using .NET but I cannot find anything in the docs.

Is there any sort of integer-based analog to the `System.Windows.Size` struct that is standard in .NET?  Something that holds integers instead of doubles?

Obviously I can

- roll my own
- pass integer width/height sizes separately
- pass `System.Windows.Size` and cast back and forth.

But I am surprised I cannot find something so fundamental already defined.  If it exists, I would prefer to use that.

Comment: Any kind of non-`int`eger coordinate system is naturally not going to use integers in it's types (`Point`, `Rect`, `Size`, `Thickness`).  Are you actually using WPF, or just looking to "borrow" a predefined type wherever you can?  Taking that dependency for a tiny bit of convenience doesn't seem like such a good tradeoff.

Comment: I am using WPF along with managed assemblies that do not.  For many of the cases where I need to pass sizes around to and from these non-WPF assemblies they are inherently integer based.  Not for shapes or controls but other things

Comment: Incidentally `System.Windows.Size` lives outside of WPF.  It is *used* by it but its not a part of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.Drawing.Size uses int32 for the height and width properties.